# Yup validation with regex using matches problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, yup

So I have below validation using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) :

```
const myValidtion = yup
.string()
.trim()
.matches(/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+/ , 'Is not in correct format')
.required();
```

With this validation, hello world passes as expected. However, what confuses me is why `hello WORLD` or `hello ,&$#$ world` also pass.

On the other hand, if we only enter invalid characters like `*%$&#$($#,` this does not pass and shows me the error. So, as I can see, it only gives me the error if ALL the entry is invalid.

What I'm looking for is how to use the Yup matches method to not pass if the user enters, for example, hello ,*&) world.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your regex should cover your whole string, by using `^` and `$` to signify start and end of string:

```
/^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+$/
```

Otherwise, it will match part of your string, which is why it matches when you have a mix of good and bad characters, but fails when every character is bad.

You can shorten the regex by using a character range like this:

```
/^[a-z]+$/
```

You can use this [online tool](https://regex101.com/) to build and test your regex.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: In order to let the space passed, we should use `/^[a-z\s]+$/`.

Comment: To allow both small/caps letters:
without space: `/^[aA-zZ]+$/`
with space: `/^[aA-zZ\s]+$/`

Comment: This answer really got me started on my first [successful!] Regex, and the tool you shared really helped me zero it in to perfect! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @HamzaWaleed `[aA-zZ]` can be simplified to `[A-z]`

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  password: yup
    .string()
    .required("Please enter your password")
    .matches(
      /^.*(?=.{8,})((?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]){1})(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z]){1})((?=.*[A-Z]){1}).*$/,
      "Password must contain at least 8 characters, one uppercase, one number and one special case character"
    ),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .required("Please confirm your password")
    .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], "Passwords don't match.")
});
```

Breaking down the regex:

(?=.{8,}): Set the minimum number of characters

((?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-*=+{};:,<.>]){1}): Verify if there is at least 1 character of the list "!@#$%^&*()-*=+{};:,<.>"

(?=.*\d): Verify if there is a digit

((?=.*[a-z]){1}): Verify if there is a lower case alphabetical character

((?=.*[A-Z]){1}): Verify if there is an upper case alphabetical character

You can test the regex code at https://regex101.com/r/rYT2yE/1.

Comment: Such a regex!What does it do?

Comment: @stevemoretz I edited the post and added what the regex does.