# Custom validation for different max date values in yup form

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

Is it possible using Yup validaion to have two different max conditions for one validation object?
So currently I have this code:

```
yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({
                        dateToCheck: yup
                            .date()
                            .min(minDatetoCheck, 'Cant be below this date')
                            .max(maxDatetoCheck, 'Cant be above this date'))
                            .required()
                    })
                )
                .when('initialValue', {
                    is: true,
                    then: yup.array().min(1)
                })
```

So I wanted to add extra check so that any date that input with year above 9999 (so like years with 5 numbers and more) should be treated as 'Invalid date format' .
I tried this:

```
        .date()
        .min(minDatetoCheck, 'Cant be below this date')
        .max(maxDatetoCheck, 'Cant be above this date')
        .max(9999, 'Invalid date format')
        .required()
```

However it is not working. Maybe is there a way to setup specific custom date form in `.date()` method that is adhering to 4 number long years only? Because the default year format allows for 5 number year long years and it is not something I need.

Comment: how about using regex to validate dateformat https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/820#issuecomment-602397774, https://bionicjulia.com/blog/yup-validation-for-date-time-with-momentjs, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746026/13405106

Comment: What if you just  change order to `.max(9999...` and `.max(maxDatetoCheck...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use test method for that in yup:

```
    .test(
      'format',
      'our Date',
      date => date.getFullYear() <= 9999
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Keyword of the problem is `test`

Here is the usage example of your case. I left last one. Because I don't understand the logic of invalid date case (`9999`). With `test` method you can make much more specific operations on your validation field. Also you can chain them. And remember it must be return boolean.

Code:

```js
yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({
    dateToCheck: yup.date()
        .test(
            'cant-below-this-date',
            'Cant be below this date',
            (date) => {
                return minDatetoCheck < date;
            })
        .test('cant-above-this-date',
            'Cant be above this date',
            (date) => {
                return maxDatetoCheck > date;
            })
        .test('invalid-date',
            'Invalid date format',
            (date) => {
                // 9999 case goes here
                // You must return true if expression meet requirements otherwise you have to return false.
                // For dispatch validation error.
            })
        .required()
}))
    .when('initialValue', {
        is: true,
        then: yup.array().min(1)
    })
```